# WatchKit app change entire screen background color

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm trying to change the entire background color of a WatchKit app using this:

```
self.group.setBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 15/250, green: 121/250, blue: 205/250, alpha: 1.0))
```

The bottom and the top color, however, remain the default black. I set the interface controller insets left, right, top, and bottom to 0, and I also set the `WKInterfaceGroup` radius to zero. What am I missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few possible problems you could be running into here.

#### Glance Interface

First off, if you are using a Glance Interface Controller, there will always be a black overlay at the bottom to account for the paging indicators. You cannot get rid of this.

#### Groups

If you are using a regular interface controller, then your group is not set up quite right. It should be "Relative to Container" for both width and height with no other sibling groups.

#### Interface Controllers

The easiest way though to set the entire background color (minus the status bar of course) is to set the background color directly on the interface controller. That will result in an image that looks like the following.

[image: Interface Background Color]

Somewhere in those answers should be the solution to your issue.

Comment: Hi @user3823935, did this end up solving your issue? If so, could you mark the answer as such? Cheers.

Comment: Hey @cnoon, Is there a way to change the entire background Color of Interface Controller from code without of setting the color from Interface.Storyboard? Thanks

Comment: Group doesn't work for me. Even though height is set to *Relative to container, 1*, actual group has minimal height.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove the top blank space is to switch the InterfaceController to *Full Screen* mode:
[image: Interface Controller settings in Attributes Inspector]

To add a color background, I would use an old method, that comes from UIKit. The idea is to stretch 1x1 image for the entire screen.

1. Go to any graphic editor and create a whitePixel.png (or copy it right here): [image: whitePixel.png]
2. Add it to your project assets and don't forget to select *Template* rendering mode. This will allow you to change color of the background without changing the asset.
3. Add an image to the controller. Set both width and height *Relative to Container*.
   [image: Image, Relative to Container]
4. With image set to *whitePixel*, select any tint color. Here's my settings:
   [image: WKInterfaceImage, Attributes Inspector]

And the result:
[image: Apple Watch screen with solid background]